# SignUp form not working with my MySqli database?

Tags: php, mysqli

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in F:\Futgraphics\backup\Website\includes\dbh.inc.php:8 Stack trace: #0 F:\Futgraphics\backup\Website\includes\signup.inc.php(9): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in F:\Futgraphics\backup\Website\includes\dbh.inc.php on line 8`

Getting this error when trying to make an account on my website.

**dbh.inc.php:**

````
$serverName = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "password";
$dBName = "futgraphicsusers";

$conn = mysqli_connect($serverName, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error());
}```
````

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade your php version to the latest one.

Comment: I have the latest one

PHP 8.1.7 (cli) (built: Jun  7 2022 21:45:53) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.7, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

Comment: Mysqli has been around since PHP 5.0 and I doubt the OP is using PHP 4 or earlier. The issue most likely that they simply haven't installed and/or enabled the mysqli extension.